# Не отрабатывают события WebSockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

Вот такой элементарный код с использованием WebSockets. При этом он не отрабатывает. При нажатии на кнопку не отправляет сообщение в консоль)

```
const App = () => {
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/');

const wsHanlder = () => {
    ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Open')
    }
    ws.onclose = () => {
        console.log('Close')
    }
    ws.onmessage = e => {
        console.log(e.data)
    }
    ws.onerror = e => {
        console.log(e.data)
    }
}

return(
    <>
        <button onClick={() => wsHanlder()}>Send</button>
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: В бразуре есть ответ о том что он поддерживает WebSocket запросы. Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket

Comment: А что вы хотите увидеть в консоли по нажатию на кнопку? При нажатии вы вешаете обработчики на события сокета, а чтоб увидеть что-то в консоли, после нажатия одно из этих событий еще должно произойти

Comment: Если вы ожидаете увидеть Open, то это событие происходит до нажатия, когда обработчика этого события у вас еще нету. Сокет то вы открываете сразу при запуске App, а подписываетесь по нажатию.

Answer (score 0):

Попытался спроектировать отправку сообщения:

const App = () => {
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/');

```
ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log('Open')
}
ws.onclose = () => {
    console.log('Close')
}
ws.onmessage = e => {
    console.log(e.data)
}
ws.onerror = e => {
    console.log(e.data)
}

const wsHanlder = () => {
    ws.send('Hi')
}

return(
    <>
        <button onClick={() => wsHanlder()}>Send</button>
    </>
)
```

}

Получил ошибку: ×
InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.